Dotnet: "Unable to load shared library 'SDL2.dll'" on Linux

I create a dotnet solution on Linux Debian (it's .NET core then)
dotnet new sln -n MySolution

Then a simple project
dotnet new classlib -n MyApp -o MyApp
dotnet sln add MyApp/MyApp.csproj


I add a reference to a package, say SDL2-CS.NetCore, in the csproj.
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="SDL2-CS.NetCore" Version="2.0.8" />
  </ItemGroup>

The sample code (in which I put SDL things) now compiles. But doesn't run :
Unhandled exception. System.DllNotFoundException: Unable to load shared library 'SDL2.dll' or one of its dependencies. 

I tried to add this in the csproj (the location is of course valid) :
<NativeLibrary Include="/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libSDL2.so" />

Same error, dotnet still looking for a .dll on Linux.
Interestingly the loader also looks for .so but after the .dll :
/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/8.0.10/libSDL2.dll.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

What am I missing ? Note that I'd prefer a "clean" solution. It works if I add a symlink SDL2.dll pointing to my libSDL2.so in the bin folder but it looks a bit clunky, while the problem really looks simple...

Does it work with Net 7?  There are still bugs in Net 8.

It does ! Thanks ! Still very strange...
